# Crash ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a Dialog Dialog and in this I would like to see all the permissions that an application requires. The package name of the application the recovery from an intent. The code is this

Unfortunately my application crashes when I open the Dialog with a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3 on                     permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");
 Why? How can i fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");
```

The above line should be present within your `for` loop. Currently its present after the `for` loop and that is why the value of `i` goes to `3`(as the `for` terminates when `i` becomes 3) giving the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I suppose you wanted to append all the permissions to the `TextView` like this.

```
for ( i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
    permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you want to put the append inside the foor loop

```
 for ( i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
 permissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");               
 }
```